# Creating my own event trigger in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I'm just a student, and new to NodeJS, so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I want to go about creating my own event trigger, but have no idea how to go about it, and if I did have some idea, I'm not sure if it would be the best way because I don't know how events work in NodeJS. For example, if I'm setting up a trigger for 'On Hover' or something, is it constantly polling the mouse behind the scenes until the cursor co-ordinates match with the hover boundaries or what?

This is the actual implementation I'm trying to achieve:

I want my program to print new news to the console whenever there is new news from BBC.com/news.

```
var request = require('request');
var parser = require('xml2json');

request('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var xml = body;
        var newsitems = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(xml)); //returns a string containing the JSON structure by default
        var item = newsitems.rss.channel.item[0];
        console.log(item.title+": "+item.link);
  }
})
```

So currently, this is just synchronous. Each time the program is run, it will print the latest news article. What I want is for it to be running infinitely and it will automatically print the latest news article whenever it changes.

Ofc, in my head, all I can imagine doing is having a while loop behind the scenes that's constantly polling the resource and will trigger the event when the resource is different to it's previous state (when it changes).

To me, this sounds as if it would slow the whole system down because you'd have something that's querying the BBC server 100% of the time. My question is, would there be any more efficient way to go about this? Should I perhaps implement a timer that polls every minute or is there a way to tell if a resource has changed or a way to get the BBC server to push the resource to me whenever it changes?